# Issues with encrypting with OpenSSL on one side and decrypting with CryptoPP [AES-128]

Tags: php, c++, cryptography, aes

I'm having some issues with encryption/decryption with different cipher suites.

On one hand, I am using PHP to encrypt a string:

```
base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($data, "AES-128-CBC", $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, "0123456789abdefg"));
```

And on the other hand, I am decrypting it with CryptoPP:

```
std::string decrypted = decrypt(dl_notdecrypted, decryption_key, "0123456789abdefg");
```

The function "decrypt":

```
std::string decrypt(const std::string& str_in, const std::string& key, const std::string& iv)
{

    std::string str_out;
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption decryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length(), (byte*)iv.c_str());
    CryptoPP::StringSource decryptor(str_in, true,
        new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(
            new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(decryption,
                new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out)
                )
            )
        );
    return str_out;
}
```

It fails with a "Unknown Exception". I am guessing this is a padding issue with OpenSSL, but I have no clue how I am supposed to fix this.

If there is any help available with this, that would be very nice.

Comment: Are the passwords/keys an exact supported length?

Comment: The passwords are SHA512 hashes of the actual passwords, zaph.

Comment: 512-bits is not a supported AES key size.

Comment: Alright, will try SHA1 hashes and report back.

Comment: Part of the problem is supplying exactly the same inputs and options and PHP does not help because encryption in inherently byte based, not string based. You will be well served to provide key, iv and data dumps (in hex) just prior to invocation and a dump just after function invocation. Making sure what types the functions expect. You should be using PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, check the defaults to make sure.  A best practice is to prepend the iv to the encrypted data on encryption and use that on decryption, the iv is not a secret.

Comment: It looks like your IV is 17 characters in both places, to boot.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski the iv is 16 characters, for some reason "c" is missing in the iv string "0123456789abdefg" so it looks like 17 characters.

Comment: Both OpenSSL and Crypto++ / `StreamTransformationFilter` seem to default to PKCS#7 padding. So that's not likely the problem. I'd rather suspect that the ciphertext or key are mangled.